# Set up DHCP client in Multipass VM

Tags: multipass

I have created a new VM with multipass via:

`multipass launch --network en1 -c 2 -d 100G -m 16GB -n microk8s-vm`

On my router I have set a DHCP reservation, and `ip a s enp0s8` confirms the correct address. The issue is my Google Wifi router requires devices to appear online to port forward and the VM is shown offline, even with internet and network access.

From [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleWiFi/comments/q3acm6/google_wifi_says_device_offline_but_device_has/) my hunch is that the machine isn't using DHCP To workaround this I want to enable DHCP on the VM.

How can I ensure DHCP is enabled in the VM?

Comment: The device getting the correct reserved IP should mean DHCP is enabled, right? Maybe the question should be "What heartbeat signal do I need to send my router to appear online"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the host machine was using Wifi. Switching to a wired connection the router was able to see the VM as online.